# How to split code when I need two actions associated to one click?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have buttons that will change their own colors on click and also a counter that will keep track of each click.
I had this working with two options:

- using the onClick function to change both the color and the counter;
- using an extra function to "watch" over the button color and add to the counter when detecting changes (code right below)

```
import React from 'react'
import { useState } from 'react'

function App() {
  const [counting, setCounting] = useState(0);
  const [buttoncolor,setButtonColor] = useState('blue');
  const [buttoncolorant,setButtonColorAnt] = useState(buttoncolor);
  
  function ButtonCreator(){ 
    function changeButton(){ 
      if(buttoncolor!='blue'){
        setButtonColor('blue');
      }else{setButtonColor('red');}
    }
    return(
      <button style={{width:200,height:200,backgroundColor:buttoncolor}} onClick={()=>changeButton()}>BUTTON</button>// 
    ); 
  }
  function checkChanges(){
    if(buttoncolorant!=buttoncolor){
      setCounting((n)=>n+1); 
      setButtonColorAnt(buttoncolor);
    }
  }

  function MakeArea(){
    return(<div className='gameArea' itemID='gameArea/'>{ButtonCreator()} </div> );
  }

  return (
  <div itemID='divapp'>
    <p className='cctext'>Click count: </p> <p className="cccount">{counting}</p>
    <MakeArea key='makearea' itemID='makearea' />
    {checkChanges()}
  </div>
  );
}

export default App
```

The problem is I have not overcome the need to have one function changing two objects/variables, and I can't split this code into separate files. I also want to avoid using global variables.

The alternate version of the code (with onClick affecting the counter directly) is this:

```
import React from 'react'
import { useState } from 'react'

function App() {
  const [counting, setCounting] = useState(0);
  const [buttoncolor,setButtonColor] = useState('blue');
  
  function ButtonCreator(){ 
    function changeButton(){ 
      if(buttoncolor!='blue'){
        setButtonColor('blue');
        setCounting((n)=>n+1); 
      }else{setButtonColor('red');}
    }
    return(
      <button style={{width:200,height:200,backgroundColor:buttoncolor}} onClick={()=>changeButton()}>BUTTON</button>// 
    ); 
  }

  function MakeArea(){
    return(<div className='gameArea' itemID='gameArea/'>{ButtonCreator()} </div> );
  }

  return (
  <div itemID='divapp'>
    <p className='cctext'>Click count: </p> <p className="cccount">{counting}</p>
    <MakeArea key='makearea' itemID='makearea' />
  </div>
  );
}

export default App
```

Comment: Use a `useEffect` that contains the logic to check for changes with the `button colour` state as a dependency.

Comment: @JohnYepthomi tried that but it didn't work, my counter just started rising to infinite without any interaction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update: Moved MakeArea into its own React component.

I'm not sure by your description as to whether the counter is supposed to be for  clicks of multiple buttons or each button. I have used the multiple buttons in my proposed solution below.

The ButtonCreator is basically a React component in its own right, so you can take it out of the main component and pass props to it. You can then give it it's own state etc. There is no problem with updating two state variables with a single onclick, but if the state is in the parent component then you will need to pass a handler down from parent to child.

Here is my proposed solution:

```
import "./styles.css";

import React from "react";
import { useState } from "react";

function ButtonCreator({ onButtonClickButtonCreator }) {
  const [buttonColor, setButtonColor] = useState("blue");

  function handleButtonClick() {
    if (buttonColor !== "blue") {
      setButtonColor("blue");
      onButtonClickButtonCreator();
    } else {
      setButtonColor("red");
      onButtonClickButtonCreator();
    }
  }
  return (
    <button
      style={{ width: 200, height: 200, backgroundColor: buttonColor }}
      onClick={() => handleButtonClick()}
    >
      BUTTON
    </button> //
  );
}

function MakeArea({ onButtonClickMakeArea }) {

  return (
    <div className="gameArea" itemID="gameArea/">
      <ButtonCreator onButtonClickButtonCreator={onButtonClickMakeArea} />
    </div>
  );
}

function App() {
  const [counting, setCounting] = useState(0);

  function handleButtonClickApp() {
    setCounting((n) => n + 1);
  }

  return (
    <div itemID="divapp">
      <p className="cctext">Click count: </p>{" "}
      <p className="cccount">{counting}</p>
      <MakeArea
        key="makearea"
        itemID="makearea"
        onButtonClickMakeArea={handleButtonClickApp}
      />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

...and here is a sandbox with it:
https://codesandbox.io/s/competent-williamson-t3zm9n?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark